# Scale the replica set using Labels

Tags: kubernetes

I could able to scale the replica set using the following

```
/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{deployment}/scale
```

Is there a way that I can do scaling based on the specific label instead of namespaces and deployment.

I could find a way to get the deployments based on label

```
/apis/extensions/v1beta1/deployments?labelSelector={labelKey}={labelValue}
```

But couldn't find scaling using label.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale Deployments, ReplicaSets, ReplicaConlrollers and StatefulSets using appropriate API:

```
/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale
/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/replicationcontrollers/{name}/scale
/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/replicasets/{name}/scale
/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/statefulsets/{name}/scale
```

The idea is to find Deployment with required Labels using API `/apis/extensions/v1beta1/deployments?labelSelector={labelKey}={labelValue}`,
and after that, use API `/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale` to scale.

You can implement this logic on ReplicaSets, ReplicaConlrollers and StatefulSets. But you need to remember, if you use Deployment, you need to scale it, not ReplicaConlroller created by it.